# Runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h) c++

Tags: c++

I know that this error refers to undefined behavior (I think), but I've reread my code 20 times and I don't see what the UB is!?

I'm doing Leetcode 238. Product of Array Except Self and here's my code (btw I don't know if this solution is right):

```
class Solution { public:
vector<int> productExceptSelf(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int> result;
    map<int, int> map;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        map[i] = nums[i];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        for(auto& it : map){
            if(it.first != i){
                result[i] = nums[i] * result[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
} };
```

Comment: You forgot to resize the result vector.

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: This goes to show you that using sites like `LeetCode` and solving some random coding puzzles is not the way to learn C++.  A `std::vector` does not grow automatically by using `[]`.  Also, sites like `LeetCode` expect that you know the language you will be using well enough to never make mistakes as you're making -- they are not designed to teach C++.

Comment: `result[i] = nums[i] * result[i];` --> `result.at(i) = nums[i] * result.at(i);` -- That should explain the issue quite clearly, since this will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: Ahhh yes, simple enough! Thank you. What would be a good way to learn then? I'm also following a coursera course, I'm sure they've mentionned this but I must've missed it.

Comment: @PhilBreezyy [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `vector<int> result;` with `vector<int> result(nums.size());`
This will initialize all of the values of `result` to 0. It won't solve the problem, but it will get rid of the runtime error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

```
result[i] = nums[i] * result[i];
```

The element value `result` is not initialized before.
Refer this:

```
if (i == 0)
    result.push_back(nums[i]);
else
    result.push_back(nums[i] * result.at(i-1));
```

if necessary